# Classpath of classes compiled with Javassist

Tags: java, javac, bytecode, java-compiler-api, javassist

As the title suggests, what is the classpath of classes compiled with Javassist?

My scenario is: Class A is compiled with Javassist. Class B is compiled with Java Compiler API and references Class A. The problem is that Class A is not visible to Class B...

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not visible"

Comment: Is the Javassist-compiled class built at runtime or is it generating a class file that is written back to disk?

Answer (score 0):

The "classpath" of class B does not depends on how the class is compiled (e.g. the class file is created), but how the class is loaded.

Java uses the class loader of a class to look up also all classes which are referenced by this class.

Each class loader can have a parent class loader, and normally `loader.loadClass` first asks its parent class loader about any classes, and in case of failure tries to load the class itself.

Thus, simply make sure the `A` class is visible to the class loader of class B, meaning that the class loader of `A` must be a parent (or parent of parent, or ...) of the class loader of class `B`.